# Drawing of Sun–Earth–Moon system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Is there a package (or packages) for drawing the Sun–Earth–Moon system with either PSTricks, TikZ, or some other vector graphics language to illustrate Lunar and Solar eclipses, the phases of the Moon, and the seasons on the Earth?

I know of [`pst-solarsystem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-solarsystem) but it is not what I'm looking for; here, it is 'only' possible to draw the planets moving in circular orbits around the Sun.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple of months ago, I produced a  `beamer`/`tikz` animation (available on [texample.net](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/earth-orbit/)) of the Earth's orbit around the Sun to illustrate the counterintuitive fact that Earth is farther from the Sun in Summer than it is in Winter. I used that example to demonstrate the power of inducing (and then resolving) [cognitive dissonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance#Education) in the classroom.

I've modified it to also show the Moon following an elliptical orbit around the Earth. (Of course, the Moon's orbit around the Earth is really only approximately elliptical, and does not lie in the Ecliptic Plane.) You can change the positions visited by the Earth and the Moon along their respective orbits (simply change how `\Earthangle` and `\Moonangle` are defined in the body of the `\foreach`, and/or modify the value of `\N`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
        \def\rS{0.3}                                % Sun radius

        \def\rE{0.1}                                % Earth radius
                                                    % Major radius of Earth's elliptical orbit = 1
        \def\eE{0.25}                               % Excentricity of Earth's elliptical orbit       
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bE{sqrt(1-\eE*\eE)}        % Minor radius of Earth's elliptical orbit    

        \pgfmathsetmacro\rM{.7*\rE}                 % Moon radius
        \pgfmathsetmacro\aM{2.5*\rE}                % Major radius of the Moon's elliptical orbit
        \def\eM{0.4}                                % Excentricity of Earth's elliptical orbit
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bM{\aM*sqrt(1-\eM*\eM)}    % Minor radius of the Moon's elliptical orbit 
        \def\offsetM{30}                            % angle offset between the major axes of Earth's and the Moon's orbits


        % This function computes the direction in which light hits the Earth.
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
            \pgfmathparse{
                ((-\eE+cos(#1))<0) * ( 180 + atan( \bE*sin(#1)/(-\eE+cos(#1)) ) ) 
                +
                ((-\eE+cos(#1))>=0) * ( atan( \bE*sin(#1)/(-\eE+cos(#1)) ) ) 
            }
        }

        % This function computes the distance between Earth and the Sun,
        % which is used to calculate the varying radiation intensity on Earth.
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{d}{1}{%
            \pgfmathparse{ sqrt((-\eE+cos(#1))*(-\eE+cos(#1))+\bE*sin(#1)*\bE*sin(#1)) }
        }

        % Draw the elliptical path of the Earth.
        \draw[thin,color=gray] (0,0) ellipse (1 and \bE);

        % Draw the Sun at the right-hand-side focus
        \shade[
            top color=yellow!70,
            bottom color=red!70,
            shading angle={45},
            ] ({sqrt(1-\bE*\bE)},0) circle (\rS);
         %\draw ({sqrt(1-\b*\b)},-\rS) node[below] {Sun};

        % Produces a series of frames showing one revolution
        % (the total number of frames is controlled by macro \N)
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\N}{12}
        \foreach \k in {0,1,...,\N}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Earthangle}{360*\k/\N}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\Moonangle}{3*360*\k/\N} % <--- change the multiplying factor to suit your needs
            % Draw the Earth at \Earthangle
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiation}{100*(1-\eE)/(d(\Earthangle)*d(\Earthangle))}
            \colorlet{Earthlight}{yellow!\radiation!blue}
            \pgfmathparse{int(\k+1)}
            \onslide<\pgfmathresult>{
                \shade[
                    top color=Earthlight,
                    bottom color=blue,
                    shading angle={90+f(\Earthangle)},
                    ] ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)}) circle (\rE);
                 %\draw ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)-\rE}) node[below] {Earth};  

                 % Draw the Moon's (circular) orbit and the Moon at \Moonangle
                 \draw[thin,color=gray,rotate around={{\offsetM}:({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)})}]
                    ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)}) ellipse ({\aM} and {\bM});
                 \shade[
                    top color=black!70,
                    bottom color=black!30,
                    shading angle={45},
                    ]   ({cos(\Earthangle)+\aM*cos(\Moonangle)*cos(\offsetM)-\bM*sin(\Moonangle)*sin(\offsetM)},%
                         {\bE*sin(\Earthangle)+\aM*cos(\Moonangle)*sin(\offsetM)+\bM*sin(\Moonangle)*cos(\offsetM)}) circle (\rM);   
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is non-animated version in the `article` class.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Eclipses}
\kant[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
        \def\rS{0.3}                                % Sun radius

        \def\Earthangle{30}                         % angle wrt to horizontal        
        \def\rE{0.1}                                % Earth radius
                                                    % Major radius of Earth's elliptical orbit = 1
        \def\eE{0.25}                               % Excentricity of Earth's elliptical orbit       
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bE{sqrt(1-\eE*\eE)}        % Minor radius of Earth's elliptical orbit

        \def\Moonangle{-45}                         % angle wrt to horizontal           
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rM{.7*\rE}                 % Moon radius
        \pgfmathsetmacro\aM{2.5*\rE}                % Major radius of the Moon's elliptical orbit
        \def\eM{0.4}                                % Excentricity of Earth's elliptical orbit
        \pgfmathsetmacro\bM{\aM*sqrt(1-\eM*\eM)}    % Minor radius of the Moon's elliptical orbit 
        \def\offsetM{30}                            % angle offset between the major axes of Earth's and the Moon's orbits



        % This function computes the direction in which light hits the Earth.
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
            \pgfmathparse{
                ((-\eE+cos(#1))<0) * ( 180 + atan( \bE*sin(#1)/(-\eE+cos(#1)) ) ) 
                +
                ((-\eE+cos(#1))>=0) * ( atan( \bE*sin(#1)/(-\eE+cos(#1)) ) ) 
            }
        }

        % This function computes the distance between Earth and the Sun,
        % which is used to calculate the varying radiation intensity on Earth.
        \pgfmathdeclarefunction{d}{1}{%
            \pgfmathparse{ sqrt((-\eE+cos(#1))*(-\eE+cos(#1))+\bE*sin(#1)*\bE*sin(#1)) }
        }

        % Draw the elliptical path of the Earth.
        \draw[thin,color=gray] (0,0) ellipse (1 and \bE);

        % Draw the Sun at the right-hand-side focus
        \shade[
            top color=yellow!70,
            bottom color=red!70,
            shading angle={45},
            ] ({sqrt(1-\bE*\bE)},0) circle (\rS);
         %\draw ({sqrt(1-\b*\b)},-\rS) node[below] {Sun};


        % Draw the Earth at \Earthangle
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radiation}{100*(1-\eE)/(d(\Earthangle)*d(\Earthangle))}
        \colorlet{Earthlight}{yellow!\radiation!blue}
        \shade[%
            top color=Earthlight,%
            bottom color=blue,%
            shading angle={90+f(\Earthangle)},%
        ] ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)}) circle (\rE);
        %\draw ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)-\rE}) node[below] {Earth};  

        % Draw the Moon's (circular) orbit and the Moon at \Moonangle
        \draw[thin,color=gray,rotate around={{\offsetM}:({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)})}]
            ({cos(\Earthangle)},{\bE*sin(\Earthangle)}) ellipse ({\aM} and {\bM});
        \shade[
            top color=black!70,
            bottom color=black!30,
            shading angle={45},
        ]   ({cos(\Earthangle)+\aM*cos(\Moonangle)*cos(\offsetM)-\bM*sin(\Moonangle)*sin(\offsetM)},%
            {\bE*sin(\Earthangle)+\aM*cos(\Moonangle)*sin(\offsetM)+\bM*sin(\Moonangle)*cos(\offsetM)}) circle (\rM);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Sun, Earth and Moon}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does the sun have a shaded part? ;)

Comment: @Jubobs One last thing: I found that the shodows on the Moon are pointing in the same direction all the time; any chance this can be made as being on the side pointing away from the Sun all the time (as with the radiation intensity on the Earth)?

Comment: It's only in the Northern hemisphere that the sun is farther away in the summer.  Which is a good way to shake loose the misconception that closeness to the sun is what makes the seasons: if that were true, the whole earth would be on the same seasonal cycle.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I'm done with this. Ask it as another question if you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the definition of `pst-solarsystem.tex` and remove all unwanted planets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solarsystem}
\makeatletter
\def\SunEarth{\pst@object{SunEarth}}
\def\SunEarth@i{{%
  \pst@killglue%
  \use@par%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,4.5)
  \psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=lightgray,griddots=10,gridlabels=0pt]%
  \pstVerb{%
   /JOUR \psk@SolarSystemD\space def
   /MOIS \psk@SolarSystemM\space def
   /AN \psk@SolarSystemY\space def
   /HEURE \psk@SolarSystemH\space def
   /MINUTE \psk@SolarSystemMi\space def
   /SECONDE \psk@SolarSystemS\space def
   %%%% Calcul du mill�naire Julien ---------------------
   /lesMois [0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334] def
   /EcartJours {lesMois MOIS 1 sub get JOUR add HEURE MINUTE 60 div add SECONDE 3600 div add 24 div add 1 sub} def
   /EcartAn {AN 4 div AN 4 div floor sub cvi} bind def
   EcartAn 0 eq {/EcartAn 1 def} if
   EcartAn 1 eq {MOIS 2 gt {/EcartJours EcartJours 1 add def}if} if
   /T {AN 2000 sub 365.25 mul 0.5 add EcartJours add EcartAn sub 365250 div} bind def
   /T2 {T dup mul} bind def
   /T3 {T2 T mul} bind def
  }%
  \rput(0,4){\psk@SolarSystemD/\psk@SolarSystemM/\psk@SolarSystemY}%
  \ThreeDput{%
    % \psframe[fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=cyan,gradend=white](-7,-7)(7,7)
    \multido{\r=22.5+45}{8}{\psline[linecolor=yellow](1;\r)}%
    \psline[linestyle=dotted]{->}(-3,0)(3,0)
    \uput[0](3,0){$\mathbf{\gamma}$}
    \uput[90](3,0){0\textsuperscript{o}}
    \uput[90](0,3){90\textsuperscript{o}}
    \uput[180](-3,0){180\textsuperscript{o}}
    \uput[270](0,-2.9){270\textsuperscript{o}}
    \psline[linestyle=dotted](0,-3)(0,3)}%
    \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradmidpoint=0,gradend=yellow,GradientCircle=true,gradbegin=gray]{0.5}%
    {\psset{unit=2}
% Earth
  \pstVerb{%
    earLM earKA earHA earQ earP orbitalparameters
    aear /radius exch 1 E dup mul sub mul
    1 E LO LP sub cos mul add div def
  }%
  \ThreeDput{%
    \psplot[polarplot=true,plotpoints=361,linecolor=red]{0}{360}{%
      aear 1 E dup mul sub mul
      1 E x LP sub cos mul add div}
    \pnode(! radius LO cos mul radius LO sin mul){Terre}}
  \rput(Terre){\psset{unit=2}%
  \pscircle[style=planetes,gradbegin=blue,GradientPos={(0.013,0.03)}]{0.0536}%
  \uput{0.08}[u](0,0){\footnotesize\textsf{Earth}}}%
  \ifPst@values
    \rput(-0.5,-4.25){\psPrintValue{LO}}
    \rput(-0.5,-4.75){\psPrintValue{0.000}}
    \rput(-0.5,-5.25){\psPrintValue{radius}}
  \fi
}
\ifPst@values
\rput(-0.5,-7.75){Earth}
\rput(-6.5,-8.42){longitude at $^\mathrm{o}$}
\rput(-6.5,-9.42){latitude at $^\mathrm{o}$}
\rput(-6.5,-10.42){distance at U.A.}
\fi
\end{pspicture}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SunEarth[Day=30,Month=02,Year=2001,
             Hour=23,Minute=59,Second=59,values=false]


\SunEarth[Day=30,Month=12,Year=2001,
             Hour=23,Minute=59,Second=59,values=false]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the orbit is circular and there is no Moon.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg From Wikipedia: “The eccentricity of the Earth's orbit is currently about 0.0167; the Earth's orbit is nearly circular.”

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: You told you are familiar with pstricks. I think you can add a moon.

Comment: @egreg Ohhh! I see. Thank you. (There is still the problem with the missing Moon.)

Comment: @egreg For exposition purposes (e.g. an explanation of the seasons), you may want to accentuate the eccentricity of Earth's orbit.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Good point. ;)

Comment: @Jubobs Eccentricity of the orbits has nothing to do with seasons. I believe that the `pst-solarsystem` package is aimed to an accurate representation.

Comment: @egreg Seasons are not explained by the eccentricity of the Earth's orbit; that's my point exactly. However, most people believe so. For a more effective presentation, you may want to present them with that conundrum first and then ask them to find an alternative (correct) explanation. In that case, accentuating the orbit's eccentricity would be useful.

Comment: @Jubobs In these terms it's indeed a good idea, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @egreg No problem :) I find that inducing cognitive dissonance in one's students often proves effective, and I used that very example in a talk to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be really accurate, you should use a programming language to simulate the trajectories.  From the examples, the eccentricities are off in the solutions above.  Here is Python code I use all the time to create this kind of stuff.  Note: I work in orbital mechanics.

Here are some notes I am working on that may help you if you want to code it up.  This notes discuss orbital mechanics.  They aren't done yet but with the link you can always check to see when it is complete.

[Orbital Mechanics Notes](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6UdM74FvKhPLTNSbDQxbTVMMWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the Earth and Mars in astronomical units.  You can add_patches for the spheres for the Sun, Earth, and Moon.  The code just needs to be changed to fit your problem.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
#  This program solves the 3 Body Problem numerically and plots the
#  trajectories

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab

mu = 1.0
# r0 = [-149.6 * 10 ** 6, 0.0, 0.0]  #  Initial position
# v0 = [-5.04769, -29.9652, 0.0]      #  Initial velocity
# u0 = [-149.6 * 10 ** 6, 0.0, 0.0, 29.9652, -5.04769, 0.0]
u0 = [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.169474, -1.0067, 0.0]
e0 = [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0]
m0 = [1.53, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.23152, 0.0]


def deriv2(e, dt):
    n = -mu / np.sqrt(e[0] ** 2 + e[1] ** 2 + e[2] ** 2)
    return [e[3],     #  dotu[0] = u[3]'
            e[4],     #  dotu[1] = u[4]'
            e[5],     #  dotu[2] = u[5]'
            e[0] * n,       #  dotu[3] = u[0] * n
            e[1] * n,       #  dotu[4] = u[1] * n
            e[2] * n]       #  dotu[5] = u[2] * n


def deriv(u, b):
    n = -mu / np.sqrt(u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2 + u[2] ** 2)
    return [u[3],     #  dotu[0] = u[3]'
            u[4],     #  dotu[1] = u[4]'
            u[5],     #  dotu[2] = u[5]'
            u[0] * n,       #  dotu[3] = u[0] * n
            u[1] * n,       #  dotu[4] = u[1] * n
            u[2] * n]       #  dotu[5] = u[2] * n


def deriv3(m, t):
    n = -mu / np.sqrt(m[0] ** 2 + m[1] ** 2 + m[2] ** 2)
    return [m[3],     #  dotu[0] = u[3]'
            m[4],     #  dotu[1] = u[4]'
            m[5],     #  dotu[2] = u[5]'
            m[0] * n,       #  dotu[3] = u[0] * n
            m[1] * n,       #  dotu[4] = u[1] * n
            m[2] * n]       #  dotu[5] = u[2] * n

b = np.arange(0.0, 2 * np.pi, .01)
dt = np.arange(0.0, 2 * np.pi, .01)
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.5 * np.pi, .01)

u = odeint(deriv, u0, b)
e = odeint(deriv2, e0, dt)
m = odeint(deriv3, m0, t)

x, y, z, x2, y2, z2 = u.T
x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z5 = e.T
x6, y6, z6, x7, y7, z7 = m.T

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(x3, y3, z3)
ax.plot(x, y, z)
ax.plot(x6, y6, z6)

pylab.axis((-2, 2, -2, 2))
pylab.show()
```

Ignore the u trajectory.  The part that will aid you is the e for earth and m for mars.  But as I said, you will need to make the appropriate adjustments.

Ignore the green path.

Here is the image this creates:

[image]

Here is a plot with a 3d sphere for you to look at too:

[image]

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added a plot that I had a 3d sphere for the Earth you can look at too.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I added a link to some notes on the subject I am creating that may help you as well.

Comment: This is really cool!

Comment: Although it is not directly connected to the question, this looks ok.