# Trouble Getting Basic Animation Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate

I'm trying to get the following simple code to animate. The first animate inline does not run, but the second does. What's wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,
begin={\begin{tikzpicture}},end={\end{tikzpicture}}
]{1}%
\multiframe{5}{iAlpha=1+1}{%
\draw (0,0) -- (\iAlpha , \iAlpha );
}%
\end{animateinline}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{1}
\multiframe{5}{iCount=1+1}{
Frame \iCount}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Frames are scaled to fit into the first frame's dimensions. Add a common boundingbox to all frames. This prevents frames 2-5 from being scaled down.

Also see this topic:
[Wrong frame size in animation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140273)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,
begin={
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \useasboundingbox (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
},end={\end{tikzpicture}}
]{1}%
\multiframe{5}{iAlpha=1+1}{%
\draw (0,0) -- (\iAlpha , \iAlpha );
}%
\end{animateinline}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{1}
\multiframe{5}{iCount=1+1}{
Frame \iCount}
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```