# Move Moon on its orbit around the Earth

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw my Moon on its orbit around the Earth. I can easily draw the moon on the perpendicular axes centring on the Earth but to move it around would probably require some trigonometry... Is there an easy way to tweak my Moon's position, keeping it in orbit? Maybe with `shift`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Earth
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \node[align=center](earth) at (0,0) {Earth};

    % Orbitz
    \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);

    %Moon
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,3) circle (0.5);
    \node[align=center](moon) at (0,3) {Moon};


\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could try using `shift` in polar coordinates: `[shift=(angle:length)]` instead of `[shift=(Xlength:Ylength)]` in cartesian coordinates (I'm not a specialist and I have not tried).

Comment: @anderstood That's the answer

Comment: Assuming the orbit is not elliptic ;)

Comment: Have you seen http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116978/drawing-of-sun-earth-moon-system?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run with `--shell-escape` and needs `imagemagick` installed.

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10pt 0pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{moon.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,preview,border=15mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\begin{document}
 \foreach \x in {5,10,...,355}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Earth
    \path[use as bounding box] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \node[align=center](earth) at (0,0) {Earth};

    % Orbitz
    \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);

    %Moon
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (\x:3) circle (0.5);
    \node[align=center](moon) at (\x:3) {Moon};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}

\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex moon}

% convert to GIF animation
%\immediate\write18{convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 400 -alpha remove moon.pdf moon.gif}
%
% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on moon.pdf moon-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{moon}{}{}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Elliptical orbits:

```
\documentclass[preview,border={10pt 0pt 10pt 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{moon.tex}
\documentclass[tikz,preview,border=-2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}

\begin{document}
 \foreach \x in {5,10,...,355}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-52]
    % Earth
    \clip[use as bounding box,yslant=0.5,xslant=0.5,circle] (0,0) circle (5);
    %\draw[use as bounding box] (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \node[align=center](earth) at (0,0) {Earth};

    % Orbitz
    \begin{scope}[yslant=0.5,xslant=0.5]
    \draw (0,0) circle (4);

    %Moon
    \node (\x) at (\x:4) {};
    \node[align=center](moon) at (\x:4) {Moon};
    \end{scope}
    \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (\x) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}


\end{filecontents*}
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex moon}

% convert to GIF animation
%\immediate\write18{convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 400 -alpha remove moon.pdf moon.gif}
%
% convert to PNG
\makeatletter
\immediate\write18{convert -density 200 -alpha on moon.pdf moon-\@percentchar02d.png}
\makeatother

\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
%\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=<integer>]{<frame rate>}{<PDF filename without extension>}{<left blank>}{<left blank>}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{10}{moon}{}{}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It always baffles me when users create animations with TeX (+1)

Answer (score 5):

The following approach uses the polar coordinates to place the moon in the orbit.
The `foreach`-loop contains the code to place the moon on an offset (orbit) at a given angle. This way you can easily iterate over your desired angles and render your image.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \newcommand{\orbit}{3}

  % Earth
 \coordinate (center) at (0,0);
 \shade [ball color=blue!10!white, opacity=.2] (center) circle (1.5) node [opacity=1] {Earth};

 % Orbit
 \draw [dashed, black!50] (center) circle (\orbit);

 % Moon
 \foreach \angle in {0,45,...,325} {
  \shade [ball color=blue!10!white, opacity=.2] (center) ++ (\angle:\orbit) circle (.5) node [opacity=1] {Moon};
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered image]

If you want to offset your labels (e.g moon) from the nodes (because you want to draw on them) you can use this approach (in the `\foreach`-loop):

```
  \shade [ball color=blue!10!white, opacity=.2] (center) ++ (\angle:\orbit) circle (.5) ++(\angle:1) node  [opacity=1] {Moon};
```

This code sets every moon label with an offset of the given angle and 1cm:

[image: Rendered image of offset labels]

Answer (score 4):

It is intentionally made as simple as possible with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}  
\psset
{
    RotX=-45,
    RotZ=-45,
    PHI=45,
    THETA=30,
    Decran=10,
    path=C:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data,
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,30,...,330}{
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \WorldMapThreeD[circles=false,blueEarth=true]
    \pscircle{4}
    \pscircle*[linecolor=lightgray](4;\i){1}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, maybe?

[image: many moons]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      heavenly body/.style={shading=ball, ball color=blue!10!white, opacity=0.2},
      moon/.pic={%
          \path [heavenly body] circle (.5);
          \node (moon #1) {Moon #1};
      },
      align=center,
    ]
    % Earth
    \shade[heavenly body] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \node (earth) at (0,0) {Earth};
    % Orbitz
    \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);
    %Moon
    \path (3,0) foreach \i in {0,...,11}
      {
        pic {moon=\i}
        arc (\i*30:\i*30+30:3)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```